# Auto resize font in sectionHeader

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I Want to show a name and some other short informations in the sectionHeader of my Tableview.

Some of the names are very large so they don't fit, is there a way to autoresize the fontsize in the sectionHeader like in a label with:

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to create a UILabel in `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)`

Apple Docu Discussion:

> The table view uses a fixed font style for section header titles. If
>   you want a different font style, return a custom view (for example, a
>   UILabel object) in the delegate method
>   tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow the code for custom header view -

1. Setup tableView

   ```
   tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 80 // You can change this value accordingly
   tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   ```
2. Implement your custom section header and return it in the delegate method

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
       switch section {
       case 0:
           return sectionHeader
       default:
           fatalError("Unreachable code")
      }
   }
   ```
3. Finally, if the contents in the header section changes while the header is presented, after the change you will have to tell the tableView to redraw itself using

   ```
   func refreshTableAfterCellExpansion() {
       self.tableView.beginUpdates()
       self.tableView.setNeedsLayout()
       self.tableView.endUpdates()
   }
   ```